# Find sum of fields inside array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data as follows:

```
> db.PQRCorp.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name" : "Ancy",
    "results" : [
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term1",
                    "score" : 1.463179736705023
            },
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term2",
                    "score" : 11.78273309957772
            },
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term3",
                    "score" : 6.676176060654615
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Mark",
    "results" : [
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term1",
                    "score" : 5.89772766299929
            },
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term2",
                    "score" : 12.7726680028769
            },
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term3",
                    "score" : 2.78092882672992
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "Jeff",
    "results" : [
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term1",
                    "score" : 36.78917882992872
            },
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term2",
                    "score" : 2.883687879200287
            },
            {
                    "evaluation" : "term3",
                    "score" : 9.882668212003763
            }
    ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is ::**Find employees who failed in aggregate (term1 + term2 + term3)**

What I am doing and eventually getting is:

```
db.PQRCorp.aggregate([ 
{$unwind:"$results"},
{ $group: {_id: "$id",
   'totalTermScore':{ $sum:"$results.score" }
  }
}])
```

**OUTPUT:**{ "_id" : null, "totalTermScore" : 90.92894831067625 }
Simply I am getting a output of a flat sum of all scores. **What I want is, to sum terms 1 , 2 and 3 separately for separate employees.**

Please can someone help me. I am new to MongoDB (quite evident though).

Comment: `{ $group: {_id: "$id"}..` should be `{ $group: {_id: "$_id"}..`. You missed the underscore `_` which is why `null` is returned.

Comment: You also might want to read the documentation for [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), considering you only want "totals" from "within the document" there is simply no need to `$unwind` and `$group` here as you can obtain the same thing with a simple projection.

Comment: thanks right....I complexed it without reason. thanks a lot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to use `$unwind` and `$group` here... A simple `$project` query can `$sum` your entire score...

```
db.PQRCorp.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "totalTermScore": {
      "$sum": "$results.score"
    }
  }}
])
```